# pandas batched API requests

Tags: python, pandas, persistence, batch-processing

I have a pandas data frame which contains a single column. With this column (as a key) a lookup a web API is performed and results are added as an additional column.

Is there a simple method to batch operations in i.e. 100 items and for each complete persist the results?

Or is the only way to achieve this to manually iterate over the dataframe in batches?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC you can use `np.array_split` to achieve this:

```
In[24]:
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(10,3), columns=list('abc'))
for chunk in np.array_split(df,(len(df.index)+2)/3):
    print(chunk)

          a         b         c
0  0.013657  0.075587  0.422208
1  0.380518 -1.941691  2.465324
2 -0.530724 -0.074501 -0.527502
          a         b         c
3  0.959920  0.282187  1.277451
4 -0.013171  1.610865  0.492687
5  0.353947 -1.406726 -0.402013
          a         b         c
6 -0.462242  1.267895 -0.477148
7 -0.735699 -0.567091 -1.212561
          a         b         c
8 -1.416133  0.355858 -0.053821
9 -0.942774 -0.331276 -0.234650
```

So [`array_split`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.array_split.html) will split the df into non-equal sized splits if it cannot split equally, so I'm passing the length of the index and to round up I add 2 so it produces a 4th chunk, if I didn't do this:

```
In[25]:
for chunk in np.array_split(df,len(df.index)/3):
    print(chunk)

          a         b         c
0  0.013657  0.075587  0.422208
1  0.380518 -1.941691  2.465324
2 -0.530724 -0.074501 -0.527502
3  0.959920  0.282187  1.277451
          a         b         c
4 -0.013171  1.610865  0.492687
5  0.353947 -1.406726 -0.402013
6 -0.462242  1.267895 -0.477148
          a         b         c
7 -0.735699 -0.567091 -1.212561
8 -1.416133  0.355858 -0.053821
9 -0.942774 -0.331276 -0.234650
```

This has attempted to simply produce chunks of size 3 as the division was rounded down.